# How dynamically to change the formula of a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to change the formula of the total grade of a student. There are two columns initially and if an add button is clicked, a new column is added also, and therefore the formula should be changed.

[image]

My formula in Excel is `=SUM(J7, H7)`, that is to add only the percent.

My problem is, I don't know how to reset the formula and change to

```
       =SUM(J7,H7,F7,D7)/[no. of items added after clicking the add button]
```

Is there any way to solve this?

Note: Columns are alternate and not in series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to this is your merged cell in C5:J5. This has a [Range.MergeArea property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822300.aspx) that defines the entire area to be considered. The [Intersect method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195772(v=office.11).aspx) can be used with a large number of even numbered columns to see which fit inside the MergeArea. Continuing to Intersect against the row involved will produce the [Range.Address property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837625.aspx) of the correct [SUM](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sum-function-0761ed42-45aa-4267-a9fc-a88a058c1a57) range.

It's a little unclear to me where this SUM function goes. The numbers in your sample do not indicate any obvious location. This uses column K and the row number is fed in as a parameter.

```
Sub main()
    new_formula rw:=7
    new_formula rw:=8
End Sub

Sub new_formula(rw As Long)
    Dim rng As Range, summative As Range
    With Worksheets("Sheet5")
        Set summative = .Rows(5).Find(what:="Summative", LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        Set rng = Intersect(summative.MergeArea.EntireColumn, _
                            .Rows(rw), _
                            Union(.Columns(4), .Columns(6), .Columns(8), .Columns(10), _
                                  .Columns(12), .Columns(14), .Columns(16), .Columns(18)))
        With summative.MergeArea
            .Cells(.Count).Offset(rw - .Row, 1).Formula = _
                "=sum(" & rng.Address(0, 0) & ")"
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

[image: summative]

            <sub>After running `main`.</sub>

Calling the sub from `main` sets a new sum formula first in row 7 and then in row 8. Adding or removing columns would require rerunning the sub but it seems likely that your columns are added by code and this could a part of that larger routine.

Answer (score 2):

Only count odd columns if your formula:

```
=SUM(IF(MOD(COLUMN(K7)-COLUMN(C7:J7),2)=1,C7:J7,0))
```

That way it will automatically resize when you add columns (provided you add them by actually inserting columns).

`K7` is the cell with the formula, `C7:J7` is all cells of the data line.

[`Ctrl+Shift+Enter`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-an-array-formula-e43e12e0-afc6-4a12-bc7f-48361075954d) to enter.

Comment: hi.. I received zero(0) output because the MOD of 8 is 2 since COLUMN(K7)-COLUMN(C7:J7) is equal to 8.

Comment: Did you press Ctrl+Shilf+Enter to enter the formula @smz? Also `MOD(X,2)` is not going to be anything other than `0` or `1`, for any integer `X`.